# Is this a type of navigation aid?

Tags: airport, antenna

[image]

I saw this contraption on the southeast corner of Eastern West Virginia Regional Airport, Martinsburg, WV (MRB). My first thought was this was some kind of NDB antenna but not sure.

Comment: Can you pinpoint it better? I don't see it here https://www.google.com/maps/place/Martinsburg,+WV/@39.4060262,-77.9711287,715m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x89ca0269b6b66563:0x96b0844a782376c7!8m2!3d39.4562099!4d-77.9638869

Comment: Air National Guard Base, might be something they use.

Comment: It’s located to the east of the cafe on the south side of the main runway on google maps.

Comment: Ok, I see it. Not airport related for navigation. No idea what it is. Not indicated on any approach chart, or the airport diagram.  https://aeronav.faa.gov/d-tpp/1908/00249AD.PDF

Comment: This could be an abandoned NDB.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to www.skyvector.com and zoom in to MRB
(easy to enter a flight from KOKV to KMRB to find it quick)

Select the World VFR view, and you will see no navaids at that location. 
Select the Enroute L-29 view, and you will see no navaids at that location.

So no, it is not a type of currently used navigation aid.

If you peruse the Instrument approaches for KMRB at Airnav.com  https://www.airnav.com/airport/KMRB

you will also not see that structure mentioned.

Airport phone numbers are listed, you could call up and ask what it is.

Comment: Main thing is, it seems to be a receiving antenna, not a transmitting one.

Comment: if it's an antenna at all. Could be part of a weather station for example. Seems to be some vehicle traffic over the grass towards it, so it is in active use and requires people to access it physically with some regularity.

Comment: @jwenting - hard to say if the tower itself is actually serviced regularly, as such tracks could easily be from people going in and out of the gate just to cut the grass inside. [Which itself could be more related to wildlife abatement than anything to do with the structure. working around old stuff is often easier/cheaper than bothering to rip it out.]